# Lodash deepClone issue when stringifying with toJSON

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

It seems that lodash deepClone has an issue when stringifying with toJSON. Please take a look at the code below.

The console output is:

```
Stringify: test_cloneThroughLodash: called
{"id":"a_1","a1s":[{"id":"a1_1"}]}
{"id":"a_1","a1s":[{"id":"a1_1"}]}
Stringify: test_cloneThroughCode: called
{"id":"a_1","a1s":[{"id":"a1_1"}]}
{"id":"a_1","a1s":[{"id":"a1_1"},{"id":"a1_3"}]}
```

while I am expecting:

```
Stringify: test_cloneThroughLodash: called
{"id":"a_1","a1s":[{"id":"a1_1"}]}
{"id":"a_1","a1s":[{"id":"a1_1"},{"id":"a1_2"}]}
Stringify: test_cloneThroughCode: called
{"id":"a_1","a1s":[{"id":"a1_1"}]}
{"id":"a_1","a1s":[{"id":"a1_1"},{"id":"a1_3"}]}
```

Notice **,{"id":"a1_2"}** in the expected output - third line.

The reason I am expecting the above is that I push one more element in the "a1s" array in the cloned object.

If I remove the **toJSON** function from class A, the output is the expected one. I tried to make toJSON public but the result was the same.

Also notice that if I clone using my own code, instantiating each object, (**test_cloneThroughCode**), the result is correct - the expected output.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export class Stringify
{
    public test_cloneThroughLodash = () =>
    {
        console.log(`Stringify: test_cloneThroughLodash: called`);

        let a = new A("a_1");
        a.a1s.push(new A1("a1_1"));

        let json = JSON.stringify(a);
        console.log(json);

        let aClonned = _.cloneDeep(a);
        aClonned.a1s.push(new A1("a1_2"));
        let jsonClonned = JSON.stringify(aClonned);
        console.log(jsonClonned);
    }

    public test_cloneThroughCode = () =>
    {
        console.log(`Stringify: test_cloneThroughCode: called`);

        let a = new A("a_1");
        a.a1s.push(new A1("a1_1"));

        let json = JSON.stringify(a);
        console.log(json);

        let aClonnedThroughCode = a.clone();
        aClonnedThroughCode.a1s.push(new A1("a1_3"));
        let jsonClonnedThroughCode = JSON.stringify(aClonnedThroughCode);
        console.log(jsonClonnedThroughCode);
    }
}

class A
{
    constructor(id: string)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.a1s = new Array<A1>();
    }

    id: string;
    a1s: A1[];

    clone = (): A => {
        let c = new A(this.id);
        c.a1s = this.a1s.map(x => x);
        return c;
    }

    private toJSON = () =>
    {
        return {
            id: this.id,
            a1s: this.a1s,
        }
    }
}

class A1
{
    constructor(id: string)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    id: string;

    clone = (): A1 => 
    {
        let c = new A1(this.id);
        return c;
    }

    private toJSON = () =>
    {
        return {
            id: this.id
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is with lodash, I think the issue is that you weren't using a constructor in the original posting. Does it work without the clone method if keep the constructor.

Comment: The following works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/meskro/qxozg5nk/

Comment: @Maria, thank you for looking into this. I can see that your code works on jsfiddle, however when I copied it on my machine it is not working any more. Your lodash is 2.2.1 and my lodash is 4.17.15. And to answer your question, my code (above) it is still not working even with constructors.

Comment: Interesting, I updated lodash on jsfiddle to 4.17.15 and it still works.

Comment: My app is an Angular app. Would that matter?